# How not to expose an app on openshift?

Tags: rest, networking, openshift

When I create an application on openshift using a tomcat cartridge the application would be exposed to the web automatically. But for some applications I dont want to let access from the outside. What should I do?
An example for that, would be having an internal service which provides a rest api to other internal applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't, every application on Openshift have to be online and facing the web.

An "Internal app" can be done using a new gear that does not expose an HTTP service to the internet but does expose an endpoint to other cartridges or by using a enterprise version of Openshift on your server, total control over your network and hence not exposed to the public web.

Comment: That's odd! Isn't that against microservices architecture? I'll mark your answer as the correct answer if no other solutions is given in the next days...

Comment: No it's not; they decided that a web app must have a connection to the public internet and that you can run other gears in the same app that does not expose their services to the internet. Those other gears can advertise their services to the application gear and you can achieve a "microservicer" architecture but it's not required

Comment: Would it be possible to create a "custom gear" of those services to acheive this goal?

Comment: Yes, the [docs](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#) are not perfect but you can get away with it, use the [cartridge development kit](https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-cdk-cart) as a template

Answer (score 1):

If you bind your app to port `8080` then your app will be publicly accessible, as stated on the [Developer Portal](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html).

Also, from the [OpenShift documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Binding_Applications_to_Ports.html):

> All ports less than 1024 are reserved for OpenShift Online operations, and developers cannot bind to these ports. However, ports greater than 1024 are available for binding
>
> ports 2303 - 2308 are reserved for OpenShift SNI Implementation, and port 10050 is reserved for the OpenShift Online Zabbix agent. You cannot bind to these ports.

So you should be able to bind to ports greater than `1024` (with a few exceptions) for local access.

Comment: I tried to bind tomcat to some other port but the application failed to deploy.